# SQL sum from different columns

Tags: mysql

I have bids table with two bids price columns *bidsprice1* and *bidsprice2*. and all users have *bidsprice1 amount*, and some users also have *bidsprice2 amount*.

I want to calculate `sum(bidsprice2)` based on `bidsprice2`, if some users have null `bidsprice2`, then based on its `bidsprice1`.

How to write this sum query?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to return the first non-NULL argument. That can be wrapped directly inside the aggregate `SUM()`.  This has the advantage of being able to add additional columns if the need arises.

```
SELECT
  /* SUM() based on bidsprice2 if non-null, bidsprice1, or finally 0 if both NULL */
  SUM(COALESCE(bidsprice2, bidsprice1, 0)) AS your_sum
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN bidsprice2 IS NULL THEN bidsprice1 ELSE bidsprice2 END)
```

In MySQL